# Button created programatically not getting styled by jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, button, styling

I'm adding rows to a table within the success() function of an $.ajax call and in the rows are some submit inputs. Here's the code that creates the rows:

```
$.each(data, function(index,element) {
    $('table#tblBranchCoverage tbody').delay(300).append('<tr class="coverageRow">' +
        '<td class="deleteCounty">' +
            '<input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteCounty" name="deleteCounties[]" value="' + element['id'] + '" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="countyCovered">' + 
            '<label class="branchCountyCovered coverageDisplay">' + element['branchCountyCovered'] + '</label>' +
            '<input type="text" class="edit editBox editCounty" value="' + element['branchCountyCovered'] + '" /><br />' + 
            '<input type="submit" class="edit button submitCoverageEdits" value="Save Changes" /><br />' +
            '<input type="submit" class="edit button cancelCoverageEdits" value="Cancel" />' +
            '<input type="hidden" id="branchCoverageID" value="' + element['id'] + '" />' +
        '</td>' +
        ...
```

The rest of the page's inputs are getting styled by the UI theme, but the buttons in the dynamically-created table rows are not.

I tried using

```
$( ".submitCoverageEdits" ).button( "refresh" );
```

from the UI button documentation. I didn't see anything else in the documentation that might apply to my situation.

Putting that line within the success of the ajax call prevented the entire table from being created. Moving the line to **after** the ajax function is call entirely didn't "break" creating the table, but the button wasn't styled either.

How can I get the UI styling applied to the buttons created in the table rows?

Answer (score 0):

After appending one row call `$('#tblBranchCoverage tr:last').button( "refresh" );` inside AJAX success handler.

Comment: I tried putting that line within the $.each() function at the very end, and even just after the each function. In both cases the table did not get built at all.

Comment: Have you moved that line from it's original position or copied it?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but I tried your suggested code right before the end of the $.each function (after the table row is closed) and also outside of the $.each function and in various places outside of the ajax call completely. (In the case of outside of the ajax call I didn't use the tr:last part though)